# Finding the order of the given matrix.

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I was posed the following question in a competitive test.
I am supposed to find the smallest natural number n such that the matrix A^n=I where A= $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        sin (10) & -sin (80) \\
        sin (80) &  sin (10) \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
where the angles are in degrees. I tried to manually calculate powers of A but even A^2 is very complicated. So I'm sure there's a way which doesn't involve computation of powers.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\sin(90^{\circ} - x) = \cos(x)$ for all $x$. So $\sin(10^{\circ}) = \cos(80^{\circ}).$ Therefore
$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{cr} \cos 80^{\circ} & -\sin 80^{\circ} \\
\sin 80^{\circ} & \cos 80^{\circ} \end{array} \right).
$$
This matrix corresponds to the linear transformation that rotates the plane by $80^{\circ}$ counter clockwise. Because of this, we can see that 
$$
A^n = \left(\begin{array}{cr} \cos (n80^{\circ}) & -\sin (n80^{\circ}) \\
\sin (n80^{\circ}) & \cos (n80^{\circ}) \end{array} \right).
$$
Since rotating the plane by $80^{\circ}$ degrees counterclockwise $n$ times will be the same as rotating it by $n80^{\circ}$ degrees counterclockwise. To get $A^n =I$, we must rotate by some multiple of $360^{\circ}$. The first time when $n80^{\circ}$ is a multiple of $360^{\circ}$ is when $n=9$. So $A^9 =I$, and no smaller power of $A$ is the identity.

Comment: Awesome. I understood the reasoning. But I think n can't be 4 since 4*80=320. I think answer is 9. :)

Comment: That's right. The minimum value of $n$ which corresponds to a rotation by a multiple of $2\pi$ is $9$.

Comment: @Shubham Thanks for catching this. I forgot the important 4*80 = 320 Lemmas and the important 9*80 = 720 Lemmas!